# getting full path of location while uploading attachment

Tags: c#

Attachment Location from desktop:

```
Nitesh.Gupta_ClientEn_2018510132928_C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\hotel.pdf
```

Uploading using

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="txt-area">
</asp:TextBox>

string filename = txtReceipt.PostedFile.FileName;
filename = txtCurrentUser.Text + "_ClientEn_" + DateTime.Now.Year +  
           DateTime.Now.Month + DateTime.Now.Day + DateTime.Now.Hour + 
           DateTime.Now.Minute + DateTime.Now.Second + "_" + filename;
```

Comment: Yes. You are. What's your question?

Comment: What if `txtCurrentUser.Text` is something like `../../SomethingSensitive`? It's a directory-traversal vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by PostedFile.FileName that contains the full path on the client machine of the file uploaded. You can get just the name with Path.GetFileName but you can also simplify a lot your code with

```
filename = Path.GetFileName(filename);
filename = $"{txtCurrentUser.Text.Trim()}_ClientEn_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}_{filename}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip it out using `Path.GetFileName(filename)` from the `System.IO` namespace.